# Unit test for insertedFact in optaplanner

Tags: unit-testing, drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

How do we unit test rules in optaplanner that depend on **insertedFact**?

As per the examples for drools, its inserting fact using **session** object and then unit testing the actual rule. How can we access session object in optaplanner? I am creating SolverFactory using xml resource.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ScoreVerifier`, explained in the docs. It's part of `optaplanner-test.jar`.